# Как улучшить верстку тестового задания

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, инспекция-кода

Оцените пожалуйста!
Какие ошибки допущены? Как можно улучшить верстку?

[Задание](http://htmlbook.ru/practical/blok-s-tenyu) | [Реализация](https://jsfiddle.net/anonymweb/e8b939mu/15/)

```css
h3,
p {
    margin: 0;
}


.box {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 35px;
}

.box_title {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  min-height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #93d81c;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  background: #c9e39c;
}

.box_title::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    z-index: -10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.box_text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 150px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding: 10px 15px 0;
    border: 2px solid #93d81c;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    background: #c9e39c;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 <h3 class="box-item box_title">Заголовок</h3>
 <p class="box-item box_text"> Содержание блока </p>
</div>
```

Comment: не выполнен следующий пункт - Блок «резиновый», т.е. тянется по ширине окна браузера

Comment: Исправил. Как можно улучшить?

Comment: `border-top`, `border-left`и `border-right` снести в один border, и потоми написать `border-bottom: 0`. Это чисто, что бы вместо трёх, было две строки :) И желательно не присваивать ничему `z-index` отрицательный. В некоторых браузерах смотрится не корректно

Comment: отступы очень важны для хорошего восприятия у вас и смотрится очень плохо. Заголовок - слева и справа, содержание блока сверху и с боков

Comment: Исправил. Но все ломается при использовании положительных значений z-index. Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за пример! Отлично попрактиковался на нем. Твой пример в IE11 не идеально смотрится(под header border/тень виднеется) Почти идеально получилось у меня, можно делать заголовок и параграф в несколько строк и все отлично смотрится! Отрицательного z-index не использую!

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.block {
  color: #510000;
}
.block h2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #C9E39C;
  max-width: 250px;
  padding: 7px 10px 13px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #A3D869;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.block h2:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #C9E39C;
  color: #C9E39C;
  z-index: 10;
}
.block p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  top: -3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #C9E39C;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 10px 11px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 105px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #A3D869;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <h2>Заголовок</h2>
  <p>Содержание блока</p>
</div>
```

Вот он на [codepen](http://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/apJQjd)

Comment: Осталось только рамку добавить.     "Вокруг блока тёмно-зелёная рамка."

Comment: Пропустил этот момент. Добавил, готово!

Comment: Хорошее решение, а я в дебри полез!